# Is there a Power Query function that seperates a comma seperate list into value columns?

Tags: excel, powerquery

Let's say that I have a column that has a comma seperated list of values in each row

```
Row ID | Symptoms
1 | Vomiting,Diarrhoea
2 | Diarrhoea
3 | Cough
```

Would it be possible to transform this into the following in Power Query?:

```
Row ID | Symptoms - Cough | Symptoms - Diarrhoea | Symptom - Vomiting
1 | No | Yes | Yes
2 | No | Yes | No
3 | Yes| No | No
```

Unfortunately could not a find a specific question and answers that tackles my challenge on Stack Overflow and tried looking up multiple videos on YouTube with limited success.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest:

- Split the symptom column by comma
- Select the `Row ID` column and `unpivot` other columns
- Add a custom column consisting of the word "Yes"
- Pivot on the Value column (containing the symptoms) and Don't Aggregate
- Replace the *null* with "No"

The code as written should adjust as you add/remove rows or symptoms from your orginal data table.

If you need to prefix all of the symptom columns with `Symptoms -` , that can be done with a few more lines of code.

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Row ID", Int64.Type}, {"Symptoms", type text}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Changed Type", "Symptoms", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv)),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter", {"Row ID"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Attribute"}),
    #"Trimmed Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"Value", Text.Trim, type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Trimmed Text", "Custom", each "Yes"),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Added Custom", List.Distinct(#"Added Custom"[Value]), "Value", "Custom"),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Pivoted Column",null,"No",Replacer.ReplaceValue,Table.ColumnNames(#"Pivoted Column"))
in
    #"Replaced Value"
```

[image]

**EDIT:**  *Provoked by @AlexisOlson comment, I added a few lines of code to both alphabetize the symptom list, and also to prefix each symptom name with the string `Symptoms -` .*

I also added numerous comments to the code, which you will also be able to see in the `Applied Steps` window.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Row ID", Int64.Type}, {"Symptoms", type text}}),

    //Split the different symptoms into separate columns
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Changed Type", "Symptoms", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv)),

    //Unpivot other than "Row ID" so as to have all the symptoms in a single column
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter", {"Row ID"}, "Attribute", "Value"),

    //Remove the Attribute column
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Attribute"}),

    //Trim the symptoms column to get rid of any leading spaces that might be there
    #"Trimmed Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"Value", Text.Trim, type text}}),

    //Sort symptoms alphabetically
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Trimmed Text",{{"Value", Order.Ascending}}),

    //Create a new column with the "Yes"'s
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Sorted Rows", "Custom", each "Yes"),

    //Pivot on the symptoms column to create new table with each symptom as a column header
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Added Custom", List.Distinct(#"Added Custom"[Value]), "Value", "Custom"),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Pivoted Column",{{"Cough", type text}, {"Diarrhoea", type text}, {"Headache", type text}, {"Myalgia", type text}, {"Vomiting", type text}}),

    //Replace the resultant nulls with "No"'s
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type1",null,"No",Replacer.ReplaceValue,Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type1")),

  firstColName = Table.ColumnNames(#"Replaced Value"){0},

  //Prefix each column header with "Symptoms - " except first
  rename = Table.TransformColumnNames(#"Replaced Value", each if _ <> firstColName then "Symptoms - " & _ else _)
in
    rename
```

[image]

Comment: Looks good. Note that if you need the symptom columns in alphabetical order, sorting that column before the final pivot should do the trick.

Comment: @AlexisOlson Good pickup. I was coding other optimizations and forgot about that. I'll make a note.